# Is there any possibility to get the last modified user details of file in C# without using Auditing or event logs

Tags: file, filesystemwatcher, last-modified

I am developing Windows service using Filesystemwatcher to monitor the folder(File share) configured in application. Along with capturing the created,removed, renamed ,changed etc event we need to get user details like who performed the particular event. I am able to get Owner details of file who created. But not the details like who modified or deleted.

note: We shouldn't take the help of event log with auditing

I have tried few solutions but could not able to get last modified user details